# Why does getch() require a key to be pressed to continue through rest of code?

Tags: c++, windows

I have a function that performs other functions when certain keys are pressed. If 's' is pressed, it
will shoot the player. if 'h' is pressed, it will just harm the player. The problem is in the
choice = getch(); below:

```
void* command(void* data)
{
    choice = getch(); //This is where the problem begins...
    cout << "Command Prompt\n\n"; //I must click enter twice to view this output. why is this???
    while (health > 0)
    {
        if (choice == 's')
        {
            playershot();
        }

        if (choice == 'h')
        {
            playerharm();
        }
    }
}
```

When this executes, for some reason, the console waits for me to press ENTER twice before it will cout << "Command Prompt";. Only after 2 ENTER's, then i will see the "Command Prompt" output. Why is getch() waiting for me to type in my letter and 2 ENTER's? Wherever else I use getch() out of this function, it works fine and doesnt usually require me to press enter. What in this code is wrong and making me press ENTER twice to finally get to "Command Prompt"? Thanks.

Comment: what platform? A Unix console not in raw mode might do this

Comment: If this is the Windows-specific `getch()` function, you should add the `windows` tag to your question.

Comment: Instead of writing `cout << "Command Prompt\n\n";` you could use `cout << "Command Prompt" << endl << endl;`. `endl` enters a new line character into the stream and also flushes it. When flushing the stream its contents will immediately appear. Your call  to `getch()` should also logically follow the output.

Answer (score 2):

`getch` reads a character from your input buffer.  Depending on how you have input buffering configured, you might not get characters typed in the buffer immediately -- they might be getting held in the driver or elsewhere until some other event occurs (such as hitting 'enter').

How you configure input handling depends on your system/OS.

Answer (score 0):

You should _getch. According to MSDN getch is deprecated, and _getch should be used:

> This POSIX function is deprecated beginning in Visual C++ 2005. Use
>   the ISO C++ conformant _getch instead.

here is the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/078sfkak%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to _getch

Comment: Interesting claim by Microsoft, as ISO C++ defines neither `getch` or `_getch`

Comment: @ChrisDodd: as I understand it, ISO C++ specifies that the names of any non-standard functions added to the C++ libraries by the vendor should begin with an underscore.